# Anyone written a script that turns gcov branch coverage output into compiler warning format?

Tags: gcov, source-insight

Most code editors know how to take a reasonably standard format of file_path, line_number, message_text and hyperlink into code. They know how because that's how they display compiler warnings. Visual Studio does it, and Source Insight is trivial to configure for that. If I have to I will write the script myself, but maybe someone has done so already.

Looking for a script that takes gcc's gcov *branch* coverage output and translates it into that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can process the output of gcov with a simple awk script:

```
/.*:.*:/ {
    split($2,tokens,":");
    LINE=tokens[1];
}

/#####:/ { print FILENAME ":" LINE ": warning: Line not executed"}

/branch/ {
    if ($4 == 0)
    print FILENAME ":" LINE ": warning: " $0;
}
```

Run with `awk -f warn.awk main.c.gcov`
and it will convert the output to:

`main.c.gcov:35: warning: branch  0 taken 0 (fallthrough)`
`main.c.gcov:37: warning: Line not executed`